# Input stream from classes made by yourself?

Tags: java, class, input, stream, inputstream

I'm currently doing an asssignment which requires me to add harnesses to a harness array. I made the class Harness so I can construct new harnesses in the main line. One thing I'm confused about is that I have to make a second class, which does the following.

Design a HarnessRecords data type (Java class) whose values (Java objects) represent the collection of harnesses owned by climbing club, that is, the current characteristics of each harness owned by a climbing club. Your data type must store a list of Harness values (using either an array or an ArrayList) and must provide at least the following operations (Java instance methods):

One of the methods in the class is to use an input stream, which takes the characteristics of the harnesses.
a constructor which takes an input stream containing the number of harness contained in the stream follow by characteristics values for each harness. The constructor creates a HarnessRecords value containing a Harness value for each one in the input stream

I tried looking up online about input streams but I've still yet to get my head around the concept. Can anyone help me with this problem?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

java.io.InputStream is a class with a simple purpose: it gives you bytes. The various read methods are the different ways you can get bytes. Different subclasses of InputStream read the bytes from different sources, e.g. FileInputStream, ByteArrayInputStream. So what the assignment is telling you to do is read a description (count and attributes) of your Harnesses from an InputStream and use that when creating a HarnessRecords.

DataInput is a useful class for this application, because it wraps an InputStream and lets you read ints, longs, Strings, etc instead of plain bytes.